# How to calculate percentage with a starting range of greater than 0

Tags: percentages

I am trying to deduce the percentage of a number `x` that is within the range of `a` and `b`.

For example, we know that 7 is 7% of 100. Given, 0 - 100: 7 is equal to 7%.
If the acceptable range was between 2 and 4, the value of 3 would be 50%. What is the mathematical equation to deduce this?

Note: I had at one point studied this, but cannot for the life of me remember the equation. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your interval is $[a,b]$. The fraction is

$$\frac{x-a}{b-a}$$

Because you subtract $a$ off so that you are now starting at $0$

Comment: Yes, this is it! Also, +1 for the clear answer.